# Maximum A Posteriori example

Tags: markov-chains, bayesian, monte-carlo, bayesian-network

In Maximum A Posteriori estimation,

$p(D|\theta)p(\theta)$

Can anyone give me a very simple example of above distributions with estimation process by MCMC?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).